# Postgis ST_Transform

Tags: gis, postgis

I have a point (x, y) with srid 900913. I transform it to srid 2180 and then again to srid 900913. Imo I should have the same point, but it differs. Why?

```
SELECT ST_X (ST_Transform(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(21.01233628836129 52.23044648850736)', 900913), 2180), 900913)),
ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(21.01233628836129 52.23044648850736)', 900913), 2180), 900913));
```

Comment: Your initial point looks like it is not in 900913, which is measured in meters

Comment: Also you don't need to do ST_X and ST_Y separately. Have a look at ST_Makepoint.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer why the two transformations were different is because of a common confusion of projection systems.

The coordinate `POINT(21.01233628836129 52.23044648850736)` on a [Spherical Mercator projection](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html) is at [0°0'1.689"N 0°0'0.680"E](https://www.google.cm/maps/place/0%C2%B000%2701.689%22N+0%C2%B000%2700.68%22E), which is *way* outside Poland, which makes it difficult or typically impossible to reproject it to anything else.

The coordinates you were looking at are *most likely* longitude/latitude on [WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/).

I think this is the exercise you were attempting (`LatLon_check` in particular):

```
SELECT ST_AsLatLonText(geom) AS LatLonText,
  ST_AsLatLonText(ST_Transform(ST_Transform(geom, 2180), 4326)) as LatLon_check,
  ST_AsText(ST_Transform(geom, 2180)) AS Poland_CS92,
  ST_AsText(ST_Transform(geom, 900913)) AS Spherical_Mercator
FROM ST_GeomFromText('POINT(21.01233628836129 52.23044648850736)', 4326) AS geom;

-[ RECORD 1 ]------+----------------------------------------
latlontext         | 52°13'49.607"N 21°0'44.411"E
latlon_check       | 52°13'49.607"N 21°0'44.411"E
poland_cs92        | POINT(637389.203455155 486840.46005323)
spherical_mercator | POINT(2339082.5759974 6841900.8700405)
```